# How to replace title with item ID when saving an item into a list

Tags: nintex-workflow

I have a list, is it possible to save the item ID as the 'title' field when saving a new item?

I have tried making a calculated value, setting it as 'ID' then linking it to the title field, but it always seems to come in as blank..

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't do it directly on the Title field. You can set a custom calculated field to equal 'ID' by going to List > Create column > Calculated (calculation based on other columns (give it a name) and then inside formula just type [ID]. Now the new calculated column has the ID value.

Answer (score 0):

Title field cannot be changed to a calculated field. You can hide the title field (go to list settings advanced and hide it there after you allow management of list items )
Use ID field available by default in each list.